# Assign event to .hide(); element

Tags: jquery

I have a couple of links that are `.hide();` on page load. These links are used to fire ajax events and I want to assign events to them.
I tried assigning events in combination with page load but the links does not have any functionality when `.show();`
So my question is should I assign events on page load or in combination with `show();`?

```
    $('.submit-reply-button').each(function(){
    $(this).click(function(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        var commentid = $(this).data('commentid');
        var reply = $(textarea.commentid).val();
        var filename = $('.mainimage').data('filename');
        var imgowner = $('.mainimage').data('imgowner');
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '?category=addimgcomment',
            data: {
                "commentid" : commentid,
                "imgcomment" : reply,
                "filename" : filename,
                "imgowner" : imgowner
            },
            success: function(data){
                $(textarea.commentid).val("");
                $('.'+commentid+'subcomments').html(data);
            }
        });
        return false;
    });
});
```

Attached to a button tag which is in turn inside an element that is hidden on page load. So there are several buttons and all are .hide(); on page load. When they show up no event is fired when clicked.

Comment: Please post the code you have.

Comment: Have you tried creating your event handlers using `on()`? http://api.jquery.com/on/

Comment: Do you mean you can't bind event to hidden elements ?

Comment: Event binding shouldn't care if the element is hidden or shown. `on()` is needed for elements that are added to the DOM dynamically.

Comment: Okay I just needed to know if .hide(); altered the functionality

Comment: You don't need `.each()`; almost all jQuery functions automatically loop over all the selected elements. But that shouldn't affect the answer.

Comment: Is your binding code inside the jQuery `ready()` handler?

Comment: Yes everything else works fine. I think it may be the each(); as you mentioned I'll try without it.

Comment: Ok, let's narrow it a bit: what happens if you insert `console.log(123);` as the first line of that `click` event handler (right before `event.preventDefault()` - which is redundant, btw)?